# Is there differences in components of saliva among species

Tags: anatomy

Are there differences in the components of saliva among species? Also, do the functions of saliva differ between species?

Comment: Some functions stay the same. For instance, at least in mammals, saliva helps to lubricate food for swallowing, begins digestion of starches by amylases and provides a liquid medium in order for taste sensation to funciton. More broadly conserved in animals is the inclusion of antimicrobial peptides in the saliva that function as a primitive immune function to keep the oral cavity clear of harmful microbes.

Comment: This question should be narrowed down somewhat. Which species are you asking about?

Answer (score 1):

It could be better answered if you specified which species you were interested in. Broadly from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saliva), snakes have venom, some swifts have gummy saliva to help in the building of nests, spiders produce their web from salivary glands etc. This is too broad a topic. The human salivary composition is found on the Wikipedia page I have linked. Salivary compositions can change with habits which have been detailed in [this article](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEMQFjAC&url=http://oralpathol.dlearn.kmu.edu.tw/case/Journal%2520reading-intern-08-04/Saliva-function-composition-J%2520Comtemp%2520Dent%2520Pract-2008.pdf&ei=YKGFU_iXKs2WuATuuIGQDQ&usg=AFQjCNHyzf9tsFJU7wswS5XzV3r3giGhBQ&sig2=lOLRci0XFxrudih33J4MRg&bvm=bv.67720277,d.c2E). To compare, I am also providing the [link to an article](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CEgQFjAE&url=http://jeb.biologists.org/content/38/1/61.full.pdf?origin=publication_detail&ei=gaGFU6yrOJSfugTisIGwDg&usg=AFQjCNGEOKV8uPNwF9qPyqFa21P3rzJwFw&sig2=KlA3JbXwFb6Kc69h5RNR8A&bvm=bv.67720277,d.c2E) on the saliva composition of an assassin bug.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but venom is technically injected and is not a normal component of saliva. Toxins on the other hand are completely normal.

Comment: @leonardo wikipedia mentioned venomous saliva so i just put it in but u are right. Toxins would be right term to use

Comment: I think the answer is not very original or authoritative. Can you try to flesh it out a little? I agree that the question is broad, but I think you could put a little more into the answer.

Comment: @jmusser Thank you for your opinion. I will have a look at it as soon as I get some time.